# How to re-design the graphics logic behind my game to preform better?

Tags: rendering, sdl, c, draw-order

Recently, I have been working on a small "pet-project" of mine in C using the SDL library. I have noticed that without my render-calls, my project takes up 2% of the CPU and with the render-calls it takes 100% and FPS drops horribly.

The project involves ants. Each ant picks a random state (Move, Turn around, Stand still) and preforms that action for a random period of time. Each ant has a collision box to detect if it has collided with a food entity and leaves a trail behind it.

A trail has three attributes:

1. Its position
2. Its strength
3. Its type (whether its a trail from the ant's home to the food or vice versa?)

The approach for drawing is as follows: in each frame:

1. Clear the screen
2. Iterate through the ant array and draw each ant from a pre-loaded PNG file
3. Iterate through the collision boxes of each ant and draw that box
4. Iterate through a trail vector that stores instances of each trail position and draw it on the screen (we need a vector as we get new trails with each moving ant)

And repeat.

[image]

Previously, before the implementation of the trail-logic, I could draw up to 10,000 ants easily. Now, I can barely handle 50. How can I improve the draw-calls to handle larger counts? I am more than glad to provide any additional information you need about the structure of the code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Typically, you'll use a profiler to try to figure out what part of your code is unnecessarily expensive. Aside from this, "we need a vector as we get new trails with each moving ant"; you don't specify what a "vector" is w.r.t. you implementation; if it is a c++ vector, adding new data to it may cause unnecessary reallocation which will kill performance. Otherwise, you seem to have "a lot" of data and iterate over it often, I suggest you look into the concept of "cache misses". On a project I worked on, optimizing data and operation for cache misses gave a nice improvement.

Comment: Above comment for profiling your code is spot. In addition, if you want folks here to profile/troubleshoot the code, we need to see a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2201/33287) so we can diagnose it rather than blindly guess what might be the problem. There's lots of ways it might be rendering inefficiently, but we don't know unless we can see how you're doing it.